# PDF export of a plot has corrupt fonts in editors on mac OS

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format, fonts

As I have explained in [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97963/pdf-font-corruption-in-inkscape-and-illustrator), I want to edit a pdf plot exported from Mathematica in Inkscape or Illustrator on mac OS but the font is corrupt:
[image]

I'm using the plot option `BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 10}` to have the numbers compatible with the LaTeX document it will be embed in.

I would appreciate if you could let me know how I can solve the issue?